# Angularfire2 Create user with new app instance shows error auth() not found

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I would like to create multiple user accounts with angular and angularfire2 plugin.

```
 let conf={
    // MY FIREBASE CONFIG 
};
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(conf, "secondary");
secondaryApp.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.staffAddForm.value.email,this.staffAddForm.value.phone).
  then(function(firebaseUser) {
    console.log("User " + firebaseUser.user.uid + " created successfully!");
    //I don't know if the next statement is necessary 
    secondaryApp.auth().signOut();
  });
```

when I run this code there is an error return like

> ERROR TypeError: secondaryApp.auth is not a function
>       at StaffAddComponent.push../src/app/layout/staff/add/staff-add.component.ts

The method definition looks like ok, but code not running properly.

Comment: Provide information on how you are requiring the `firebase` module. It is possible you are not adding the Auth dependency.